# In complex analysis, can a zero be a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I try defining the function as follows:

$$ f(z)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{|z|} & \text{if } z \ne 0
\\
0  & \text{if } z = 0
\end{cases}
$$

By taking the limit when you approach $z=0$, you get $L= \infty$  (a pole)
Nevertheless, $f(0)=0$  (a zero)

Is this true?

Comment: $1/|z|$ isn't analytic, so talking about poles doesn't make sense.  But even if you took $1/z$, the pole at $0$ has to do with the limiting behavior.  A zero can't be a pole.

Comment: @saulspatz: It **is** a pole if you modify it to $1/z$. Firstly, it is an isolated singularity since $f$ it not analytic at $0$ and is analytic everywhere else. Secondly $z \mapsto zf(z)$ is holomorphic at $0$, whereas $f$ is not. Thus, $0$ is a pole of order $1$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Who said $1/z$ doesn't have a pole?

Comment: @saulspatz: Oh, maybe I misinterpreted your earlier comment but my point was: Consider the function $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ defined as $$f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{z} & z \neq 0 \\ 0 & z = 0 \end{cases}.$$ Then, $0$ is a pole of $f$. However, $f(0) = 0$ is also true.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I understand your point, but it isn't the zero of an analytic function.  It is not customary to consider functions of this sort in complex variables.